# titanium alloy framework build error

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy, genymotion

it gives me an error of "Cannot call method createimageview of undefined file"

```
var imgpldt= Ti.Ui.createImageView({
image: "sponsors/Home DSL.png"
});

$.pldt.add(imgpldt);
```

heres the xml:

```
<Alloy>
<ScrollView class="container vertical whitebg actionBarTop">
    <View class="sponsorWrapper blackbg vertical">
        <View class="sponsorLogo" id='pldt'/>
        <View class="whitebg socialContainer">
            <View class="socialWrapper horizontal whitebg">
                <ImageView class="top10" id='pldtFB' image="/facebook.png"/>
            </View>
        </View>
    </View>
</ScrollView>
</Alloy>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arkaem,

You have done very small mistake, `Ui` change it to `UI` as below and then test it.

```
var imgpldt= Ti.UI.createImageView({
 image: "sponsors/Home DSL.png"
});
```

Comment: btw, i did this because I just want the app to load the images when sponsors page is clicked..am i on the right path? i would also like the images to be remove when The user goes to another page